# How to separate this declaration into a separate file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, declaration

I have a really long string (reallyLongString below)    and want to put its declaration/definition in a separate file from the main code.
How do I do that? Thanks.
Can I just surround it with `"public partial class MainWindow: Window {" and "}"` in another file?

```
namespace MyApp
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        string reallyLongString = "...";
     ...
     }

...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes basically, although I think you can only specify the sub-type once. So in one file:

```
namespace MyApp
{   
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        // main code
    }    
    // etc...
}
```

And in the other:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        string reallyLongString = "...";
    }
}
```

You could also look at a resx or an embedded resource, rather than a literal.

Comment: @SurjitSamra: The difference in compilation speed would be negligible. Most likely it would compile faster with everything in a single file, since the compiler wouldn't have to open that second file. But we're talking milliseconds.